# how to delete users generated by make:auth laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm having some trouble while deleting or updating any users in the list. The users don't want to be deleted. The error is

> "Class 'App\Role' not found"

and I have no class role.

If someone has some idea about delete user generated by `make:auth`, I will be grateful.

This is the code:

The route:

```
Route::POST('destroyUser','UserController@destroy')->name('destroyUser');
```

The controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)  {                                                                                    
    $user= User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('message','l\'utilisateur '.$user->name.' a été supprimé avec succès');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Laravel `make:auth` doesn't come with `Role` model, this is your fault in the code, find the missing model and remove it from your code by using `search` in your `IDE`

Comment: You should also check if u have installed some library which handles `roles` like `spatie/permissions` or something similar

Comment: thank you bro it work now you are the best